# Finding a matrix representation of a linear endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Consider the following basis of the vector space of $2 \times 2$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$:

$$ e_1 = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) $$

$$ e_2 = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) $$

$$ e_3 = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) $$

$$ e_4 = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) $$

Now, say we have an endomorphism $T: M(2,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M(2,\mathbb{R})$ and we know the image of each basis element. How would I go about construction a matrix representation of $T$? Thank you!

Comment: Note that $T$ should be a $4\times4$ matrix, since $M(2,\mathbb R)$ has dimension $4$

Comment: Yeah! I think I know how to do it then. It's just that this fact confused me because then when applying the transformation as a matrix, we would have a $4 \times 4$ matrix being multiplied by a $2 \times 2$ matrix... which is impossible.. so I got confused.

Comment: apply the transformation to the coordinates, which are $4\times1$ matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that, say,$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}a+b&c+d\\a-d&b-c\end{bmatrix}.$$Then$$T\left(e_1\right)=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}=e_1+e_3$$and therefore the entries of the first column of your matrix will be $1$, $0$, $1$, and $0$, since $T(e_1)=1\times e_1+0\times e_2+1\times e_3+0\times e_4$. And so on…

Comment: It seems weird to me that we will get a $4 \times 4$ matrix, since it represents a linear transformation that will act on a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Comment: Since the space of all $2\times 2$ has dimension $4$, there is nothing strange in it.